# mezzanines css and js files not loading for django project

Tags: django, mezzanine, django-filebrowser

I am new to django and the mezzanine, i have set the mezzanine for my django peoject.
but when i load the admin login page i get this is my server logs these files are supposed to load but i am getting 301 or 404 response code from there.

```
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 301 0
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/css/admin/global.css HTTP/1.1" 301 0
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/js/admin/login.js HTTP/1.1" 301 0
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/css/admin/global.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 112
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/js/admin/login.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 109
 [14/Apr/2014 10:23:12] "GET /static/mezzanine/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 114
```

screen shots are attached.

this is my setting file:
      import os

```
  #=====================#
  # DJANGO #
  #=====================#
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  ADMINS = (
      # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
  )
  MANAGERS = ADMINS
  TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
  USE_TZ = True
  LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
  DEBUG = True
  SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
  SITE_ID=1
  USE_I18N = True
  SECRET_KEY = '!0nlw*q%l(m6xovqy2m4&*qo6&g*!09007*9!qr0#4j#ex-ndk'
  INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1",)
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
  WSGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.wsgi.application"      

  TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
      "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
      "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
  )      

  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("mezzanine.core.auth_backends.MezzanineBackend",)      

  STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
      "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
      "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
  # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
  )      

  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
          'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
      }
  }      




  #=====================#
  #PATH
  #=====================#
  PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]
  CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = PROJECT_DIRNAME
  FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
  STATIC_URL = "/static/"
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
  COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
  MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
  ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"
  ROOT_URLCONF = "%s.urls" % PROJECT_DIRNAME
  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)
  # FIXTURE_DIRS = PROJECT_ROOT.child("fixtures")      



  #=====================#
  # APPLICATIONS #
  #=====================#      

  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      # "djnaog_toolbar",
      # "django_extensions",
      "django.contrib.admin",
      "django.contrib.auth",
      "django.contrib.contenttypes",
      "django.contrib.redirects",
      "django.contrib.sessions",
      "django.contrib.sites",
      "django.contrib.sitemaps",
      "django.contrib.staticfiles",      

      "mezzanine.boot",
      "mezzanine.conf",
      "mezzanine.core",
      "mezzanine.generic",
      "mezzanine.blog",
      "mezzanine.forms",
      "mezzanine.pages",
      "mezzanine.galleries",
      "mezzanine.twitter",
      'youtube',
      "south"
      # 'filebrowser_safe',
  )
  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
      "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
      "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
      "django.core.context_processors.debug",
      "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
      "django.core.context_processors.static",
      "django.core.context_processors.media",
      "django.core.context_processors.request",
      "django.core.context_processors.tz",
      "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
  )
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
      "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
      "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
      "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
      "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
      "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
      "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
      # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
      # "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
      "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
  )      

  PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
  PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"      

  OPTIONAL_APP={
      "debug_toolbar",
      "django_extensions",
      "compressor",
      PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER,
      PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI,
  }      




  #=====================#
  # MEZZANINE
  #=====================#
  ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
      ("Content", (("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
      ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
      ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
  )
  DASHBOARD_TAGS = (
      ("mezzanine_tags.app_list",),
      ("comment_tags.recent_comments",),
      ("mezzanine_tags.recent_actions",),
  )
  BLOG_USE_FEATURED_IMAGE = True
  USE_SOUTH = True
  GEOPOSITION_DEFAULT_ZOOM = 5
  GEOPOSITION_DEFAULT_CENTRE = (21.77, 78.87,)      

  DEVICE_USER_AGENTS = (
      ("mobile", ("Android", "BlackBerry", "iPhone", "Windows Phone")),
      ("desktop", ("Windows", "Macintosh", "Linux")),
  )      

  # RICHTEXT_WIDGET_CLASS = 'pari.article.forms.TinyMceWidget'
  #
  # RICHTEXT_FILTERS = (
  #     'pari.article.rich_text_filter.article_content_filter',
  # )      

  FORMS_USE_HTML5 = True
  ACCOUNTS_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED = True
  SSL_FORCE_URL_PREFIXES = ("/admin", "/account", "/asset_proxy")
  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')      

  SEARCH_MODEL_CHOICES = (
      "pages.Page",
      "youtube.Youtube",
  )      



  try:
      from local_settings import *
  except ImportError:
      pass      



  try:
      from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
  except ImportError:
      pass
  else:
      set_dynamic_settings(globals())
```

### urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin


 from mezzanine.core.views import direct_to_template

 admin.autodiscover()

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     # Examples:
     url(r'^$', 'youtube.views.upload'),
     url(r'^uploaded','youtube.views.uploaded'),
     # url(r'^$', 'youtube.views.root'),
     # url(r'^upload','youtube.views.upload'),
     # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
     # url(r'^admin/filebrowser/',include(site.urls)),
     url(r'^grappeli/',include('grappelli.urls')),

     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


     url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
     url("^$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),
     ("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
     ("^", include("filebrowser_safe.urls")),

 )

 handler404 = "mezzanine.core.views.page_not_found"
 handler500 = "mezzanine.core.views.server_error"
```

here are the screenshots attached for what i expect to be and what i am getting in my django project:

expected login and dashboard screen:
[image: normal mezzanine screen(which is what i want)]

[image: expected dashboard for mezzanine]

actual login screen and the error after clicking on the media library icon:
[image: my django admin login after mezzanine integration]

[image: after clicking on the media library in my project]

Answer (score 0):

What installation steps did you follow? The [install steps in the
documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#installation) worked fine for me:

```
pip install south pillow django-compressor
pip install mezzanine
mezzanine-project test_project
cd test_project
python manage.py createdb --noinput
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: its not mezzanine project, its a django project and i am adding mezzanine interface there for admin site

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots for what you expect show the Grappelli skin for Django admin.

For mezzanine you want

```
pip install grappelli-safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks to be working correctly...

Your screenshot shows you going to

**localhost:8000/browse/**

In your urls.py there is no mention of browse/

In your browser, you need to go to:

**localhost:8000**

or for admin:

**localhost:8000/admin/**

if you want to see any content.